# How to echo data as it in table

Tags: php, html

I have this code that gets data from DB then echo it. How can I make the code echo data as it in table like this:
[image]

**Code:**

```
$username = $_POST['username'];

$connnn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "0598985166sallam", "project");
$sqllll = "SELECT value, status,no FROM bill WHERE username = '$username'";
$resulttt = $connnn->query($sqllll);

if ($resulttt->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $resulttt->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr> <td>$row[no]</td> <td>$row[value] </td> <td> $row[status]</td></tr>";
    }
}
```

Comment: looks like your 90% there, whats the issue your facing currently?

Comment: data is printed at the top of the page, while I need it to be printed in table inside my html code. How can I solve this problem? @nogad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand your question correctly then i think you are finding this solution :

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$connnn   = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "0598985166sallam" ,     
"project");
$sqllll   = "SELECT value, status,no FROM bill WHERE username = '$username'";
$resulttt = $connnn->query($sqllll);
if ($resulttt->num_rows > 0){
   echo "<table class='anyClass'>";
   echo "<tr>
             <th>Bill Num</th>
             <th>Bill Val</th>
             <th>Bill stuts</th>
        </tr>";
   while($row = $resulttt->fetch_assoc())
      echo "<tr> 
              <td>".$row[no]."</td> 
              <td>".$row[value]."</td> 
              <td>".$row[status]."</td>     
          </tr>";
  echo "</table>";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. the table is already created, but it locates at the top of the page, how can I change its place to fit where I want? @Manpreet

Comment: use css or js or html(<br/>).. I dont know how is your page look like

Comment: I put my php code where I need the result to be shown, it is ok. Thank you @Manpreet